# Кодировка в AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax, xml, кодировка

Моя страница, которая получает ответы в кодировке utf-8, страница на которую шлю запросы тоже utf-8. У меня значение которое получает ajax ответом идёт в поле формы. И по какой-то причине в форму вставляется в юникоде, но кракозябрами, как будто кодировка кириллица. Ну я преобразовал с помощью функции iconv ответ в кириллицу, но т.к. обработчик у меня XML, мне выдаёт ошибку о недопустимом символе и действительно создаётся какой-то квадратик "FF".
Но если шапку о том что это xml убрать квадратика не образуется. Подскажите пож-та как избавиться от квадратика, или как сделать чтобы в полях формы была кодировка юникод.

Comment: А ты не рассматривал как вариант гонять данные в json формате? к тому же их ещё и проще использовать из js

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня никогда не было таких проблем, всегда пользовался xml.

Comment: я тоже им всегда пользовался, пока не научился работать с json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мда, оказывается надо было передавать имя в обработчик пропуская через функцию `encodeURIComponent`. Бред, никогда так не делал и не встречался с проблемами. Но главное победил я всё-таки) Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Так если страница в ютф-8 и аякс отправляется в ютф8 (аякс запрос всегда в этой кодировке), надо проверить файл, который запрос обрабатывает, его кодировку и на наличие в нем левых символов, все ли там нормально

Comment: Я пол дня уже проверяю оброботчик, там всё нормально и если открывать ччерез браузер обработчик, то всё отлично отображается

Comment: Не могу почему то там добавить коммент, нет, всё в одном файле, самое интересное что если просто текст писать, то он нормально выводиться, а если выводить переменную, то кракозябрами почему-то

Answer (score 1):

Уверен, что ответ приходит в utf?
Когда отдаешь аяксовый ответ, перед выводом добавь

```
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Вместо `text/html` поставь, что нужно.

Comment: у меня xml, и написано header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');

Comment: @Ну я преобразовал с помощью функции iconv ответ в кириллицу@

И отдаешь с заголовком charset=utf-8?

Comment: Нет, я преобразовывал чисто для теста. Но и без преобразования ерунда получается.

Comment: А откуда данные берутся, которые в ответе приходят? И можешь скопипастить строку, которая в инпуте появляется?

Comment: Скрипт работает так: вводишь своё имя, в другое поля забивается имя в дательном падеже, пишу в поле имя "Тест", в поле дательный падеж должно быть написано "Тесту", а пишет "РўРµСЃС‚"

Comment: Да, сейчас попробывал ничего не генерировать, а написал просто, чтобы всегда в ответ шло слово "Тесту" - всё нормально. Но я не понимаю почему проблемы с генерацией, там везде кодировка проставлена юникодовская

Comment: а обработка ajax случайно не во внешнем js файле? может быть он в ansi?